# Parsing and accessing variables containing '$' in Makfile

Tags: sed, makefile, preprocessor

I have gotten myself into Makefile-hell :(

I have a file `test.par` containing values:

```
$ABC=123   ! some comment
$DEF=456   ! comment
```

and I have a template source file (actually in fortran, but that does not make a difference here) `test/template.c`:

```
int main(void) {
    return $ABC+$DEF ;
}
```

and I want to set the values in the code, like a preprocessor would do. So I wrote a target in my Makefile like so:

```
default:
    for f in test/*; do \
        while read l ; do \
            key="$$(echo $$l | cut -d "=" -f 1 | tr -d ' ')";\
            val=$$(echo $$l | cut -d "=" -f 2 | cut -d " " -f 1);\
            [[ -z "$$val" ]] && \
                val=$$(echo $$l | cut -d "=" -f 2 | cut -d " " -f 2);\
            echo $$key $$val;\
            cp $$f $$f.out ;\
            sed -i "s/$$key/$$val/g" $$f.out;\
        done < test.par;\
    done;
```

I go through every file in test/ (there are many) in the for loop and "apply" every line in `test.par` in the while loop.

The expected result is

```
int main(void) {
    return 123+456 ;
}
```

What I get is

```
int main(void) {
    return $ABC+456 ;
}
```

And now it is getting crazy: If I switch the to lines in the `test.par` file, I get:

```
int main(void) {
    return 123+$DEF ;
}
```

If there are more lines, there no substitution at all.

What is wrong with me!!!???!!!

**edit:** I cannot make too many changes to the original code, so aI was hoping to solve this in the Makefile.

Comment: It would be a good idea to factor out the actual modifications into a script and just call the script in your Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep reusing the original file for substitutions, so only the last one actually sticks (the result of all substitutions but the last is overwritten by the next). After

```
            sed "s/$$key/$$val/g" $$f > $$f.out;\
```

put

```
            cp "$$f.out" "$$f";\
```

to fix this. (Or make a working copy of `$$f`, if you want `$$f` unchanged, e.g., `cp "$$f" "$$f.out"` before the loop and use `sed -i "s/$$key/$$val/g" "$$f.out"` inside.)

Comment: That was definitely a bug, but the Problem remains

Comment: Do the `cp` before the loop, not inside it, or you'll have the same problem again.

Comment: You just saved my weekend!

Comment: Though it would be more robust and elegant to just run `sed` once. Or twice; if your `sed` can eat a script on standard input with `-f -` then this should be a simple two-liner. [Google examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+"sed+-f+-")